# Finding the biggest value in 2D array

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array

2D array is given

```
2 1 5 2 7
2 4 5 1 2
9 2 4 1 0
6 5 4 3 2
```

Need to find the maximum sum of values.
We can start from the first row and then move in directions: left-down, down or right-down
In this example it is: 5 - 4 - 9 - 6 = 24
I got an idea to transform this array into tree with 3 "childs" (left, down and right).
And using this tree, count the sums of all branches assuming that every element in first row is a root of different trees.
Maybe, have some other advice or solution, because I am not able to make it work.
Here is a code of finding sums of all branches:

```
def branchHelper(root, sums=None, branchSum=0):
if root is None:
    return

if sums is None:
    sums = []

branchSum += root.value
if root.left is None and root.right is None and root.middle is None:
    sums.append(branchSum)
branchHelper(root.left, sums, branchSum)
branchHelper(root.middle, sums, branchSum)
branchHelper(root.right, sums, branchSum)
return sums
```

And Tree code:

```
class Tree:
def __init__(self, value, left=None, middle=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.middle = middle
    self.right = right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's classic issue of dynamic programic. You don't need to transform the array to tree, just iterate through it. That's faster and easier to write. All you have to do is calculate for each array element how much can you collect in a path ending in this element. In the first row - you have no choice, there's only one path. Then, in k-th row - you know that you can only come here from one of 3 array fields in the (k-1)-th row, and you know exactly from which. Just choose the best :)

Comment: I still don't fully understand how to make the real code, can you please write at least part of it?

Comment: You iterate over rows and for each element you replace it with sum of this element and maximum of the elements above (elements above in the tree, that is one row above).

    `2 1 5 2 7`
    `4 9 10 8 9`
    `18 12 14 11 9`
    `24 23 18 17 13`

Comment: Try to simulate it on paper, so you can understand the algorithm and then writing code would be easy :) In your example, second row: first column [2, 1] - I could come here from [1, 1] or  [1, 2] - I choose [1, 1] because 2>1. Answer for [2, 1] is 2 (from previous rows) + 2 (from this field). Then second column, field [2, 2] - could come here from [1, 1] or [1, 2] or [1, 3]. Choose [1, 3]. Total value is 5+4.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll practice more in such types of tasks..

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is the one above. In addition, I attach the code so that you have something to follow.

```
arr = [[2, 1, 5, 2, 7],
       [2, 4, 5, 1, 2],
       [9, 2, 4, 1, 0],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]]

def get_max_parent(index, previous_row):
    left_parent = index - 1 if index > 0 else 0
    right_parent = index + 1 if index < len(previous_row) - 1 else len(previous_row) - 1

    return max(previous_row[left_parent], previous_row[index], previous_row[right_parent])

def solve(l):
    current_row = arr[0]
    for row in arr[1:]:
        previous_row = current_row[:]
        for index, elem in enumerate(row):
            current_row[index] = row[index] + get_max_parent(index, previous_row)

    return max(current_row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve(arr)
```

Comment: I have already managed to do it by myself, but thanks.
Your version is also nice.